# How to change parent's state depends on childrens state

Tags: reactjs

Let's imagine I have this render method:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className={`parent${this.state.isActive ? ' active' : ''}`}>
            {[...Array(3)].map((x, i) =>
                <Checkbox id={`checkbox_${i}`} />
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

`<Checkbox />` component here creates simple input + label element wrapped in `div`. My task here is to set parent's state `isActive` depends on any of checkboxes are checked. E.g. if single input is checked then `isActive` should be **true**, but if none of checkboxes are checked it should be **false**. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: see [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an event handler function as props to `Checkbox` components, for example:

```js
// The event handler passed to Checkbox
handleChecked () {
  this.setState({ isActive: false });
}

// Passing the function like
<Checkbox handleChecked={this.handleChecked} />
```

Dont forget to bind the function to `this`

Comment: My question was about how could one component know if his siblings are `checked` or not. I'm sorry if it wasn't clear.